# Registration of a user and subsequent activation by the admin with django-rest-framework and djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I would like to create a user that is activated by the system admin with `djoser` and `django-rest-framework`. The sequence of operations that I would like to obtain is the following:

1. a user sends the registration request
2. the user is saved in the database but remains inactive
3. an email is sent to the admin informing that a new subscription has been requested
4. the admin activates the user from django admin panel
5. when the user has been activated, an email confirming the activation is sent to him.

I can do this with django in the following way:

**signals.py**

```python
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='register')
def register(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False) and not instance.is_active:
        mail_admins('User registration request', 
        f"A registration request was made by the user:\n\n{ instance.username }\n{ instance.email }",
        fail_silently=False, )


@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='active')
def active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_active and User.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk, is_active=False).exists():
        subject = 'Account activation'
        mesagge = '%s your account has been successfully activated!' %(instance.username)
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        send_mail(subject, mesagge, from_email, [instance.email], fail_silently=False)
```

**views.py**

```python
class UserRegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    template_name = 'users/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        return redirect('request')
```

**forms.py**

```python
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**urls.py**

```python
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('users/register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'), 
    ...
]
```

However with `django-rest-framework` and `djoser` I can only register a user who is already active, or set the registration by confirming by the user with the commands

```python
DJOSER = {
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True
}
```

In addition, other setting parameters are

```python
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

and

**urls.py**

```python
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
    ...
```

I manage front-end of my project via `vue-cli`, but I think the problem needs to be solved in the back-end.

Is it possible to get what I want with `django-rest-framework` and `djoser`?